# Can normal people suggest their own filter design?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, april-fools

Today we can see that there are many cool designs available for the user interface with some people's names. For example, "Bookface by Tom" and so on.

Are they staff or moderators or just random people like us? Is it possible to suggest any design to Stack Overflow?

Comment: That Tom filter was created by me. So give your "thanks" to me, please. JK, I guess "Tom" is a reference to the default MySpace friend everyone got when they created an account there.

Comment: Today we learned a generation does not know about MySpace.

Comment: The names are part of the joke.

Comment: Sorry, but that Frisa Lank theme needs dolphins and unicorns

Comment: Normal people no, just the amazing ones.

Comment: What is normal, anyway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They aren't the creators of the themes, or random people:

- "3D glasses" by **D**igital **D**imension **D**esigners
- "Bookface" by [Tom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Anderson)
- "Hot dog stand" by [The Delicious One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Delicious_One)
- ["Frisa Lank"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_Frank) by Child of the ’90s*
- "MariOverflow" by [Luigi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi) Luigi
- "Terminal" by [Neo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_(The_Matrix))
- "Top Secret" by Agents [J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_J) & [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_K)
- "Windows 3.1" by [Ms. Dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS)

* *I suspect this one's backwards...*

Comment: I always thought Mark developed Bookface.

Comment: Luigi Luigi is definitely backward.

Comment: Mark stole the idea from Armie Hammer. Both of him. There was a whole movie about it. It won Oscars.